# How to rebuild resource.h file? - RC1015 cannot open include file 'resource.h'. -

Tags: windows, visual-c++, resources

I am trying to put together a DirectX hooking/injection example using an old DX library, d3dx9, in VS 2017 Community.

Project here: https://github.com/stimmy1442/EndSceneHookExample

After a painstaking experience of getting the include and library directories in the right order, I was able to get the InjectedDLL built, but I have run into another issue with the DLLInjector.  When I go to build it, I get the following error: `Error    RC1015  cannot open include file 'resource.h'.`

resource.h is called from the DLLInjectV2.rc file that I have posted below.  From what I understand about resource files(not a lot), is that this particular file should just *be there*.  I have checked the resource path and when I created a resource.h in *C:\Users\Skew\source\repos\DLLInjector\DLLInjectV2* and filled it with the code found here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/resource-h) I get the following error instead: `Error   RC1004  unexpected end of file found`

I feel like I might be on the right track, but I believe my lack of understanding windows programming and resource files is holding me back.  Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this issue, and possibly a good resource to more easily understand windows resource files?

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Deutsch (Deutschland) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_DEU)
LANGUAGE LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_GERMAN

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040704b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Stimmy"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "DLL Injector for Halo Trainer"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "DLLInject.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyleft"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "DLLInject.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "DLLInjector"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x407, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // Deutsch (Deutschland) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: Since your .rc file doesn't seem to define any ID_* resources, and typically resources.h just assigns numbers to the ID_*, you might get away with an empty file. (Or drop the .rc altogether.) But it's probably worth raising an issue on GitHub about this, in case stimmy1442 still has their original build tree and can just check the file in for you.

Comment: Thank you Rup, using a blank resource.h file did the trick.  I will definitely message Stimmy1442 and let him know.